# 301-й редирект в Wordpress (с домена без www на домен с www)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Содержание файла .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Пробовал дописать

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

или

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

или

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Ни один из этих вариантов не работает. Что делаю не так?

Comment: Нужно сделать переадресацию с домена без www на домен с www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел таже возможность сделать основным домен с www или без в настройках вордпресса в админке (Настройки -> Основные)